# Разбор условия if(?:) return;

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно озвучить данное условие if()

```
if (name == null ? !name.equals(human.name) : human.name != null) return false;
```

Мое предположение:
Если name пуст, то если name не равно human.name ...дальше мысль теряется. Иначе если name не пустой, то если human.name не пустой ... та же ерунда мысль не улавливаю. При каком из вышеперечисленных и совпадающих условий return false;?

Comment: Если name будет null, то в вашем коде будет `NullPointerException`, из-за `name.equals`

Comment: gil9red а если не null, то предполагаю,будет еще одна проверка -> если и `human.name = null` , то тоже будет ислючение и сработает `return false;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что в скобках:

Если name == null, вычисляется "!name.equals(human.name)"

Если нет, вычисляется "human.name != null"

Оба выражения возвращают тип boolean.

Ну и выражение за скобками: если (найденный boolean == true) вернуть false.

Comment: Максим Степанов а если  (найденный boolean == false), то все равно вернется false, т.е. в любом случае вернется false?

Comment: Нет, если то, что в скобках, будет иметь значение false, то, что за ним просто не выполнится. То есть код "return false;" после скобок выполнен не будет.

Comment: Ничего. чтобы вернулось, нужно так: if(то что в скобках) {return false;} else {какой-то другой код, например "return true;"}

Comment: Разобрался благодарю)

Comment: Но если `name == null`, то никакого "вычисляется `!name.equals(human.name)`" не будет, будет NPE

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но задача была расписать условие "if" устно, что я и выполнил =). А вообще да, попытка проверить, содержит ли что-то пустое "name" некорректна.

Comment: Да действительно так. Кстати только

Comment: посмотрел на свой вопрос с новой стороны. if(true) return false; и все становится на свои места :D

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, в таким случаях надо по шагам преобразовывать код:

```
if (name == null ? !name.equals(human.name) : human.name != null) return false;
```

**1 шаг:** выделяем boolean

```
boolean flag = name == null ? !name.equals(human.name) : human.name != null;
if (flag) {
   return false;
}
```

**2 шаг:** превращаем оператор ?: в просто if

```
boolean flag;

if(name == null) {
   flag = !name.equals(human.name); 
   // null.equals(human.name); - выкинет NullPointerException
} else { 
   flag = human.name != null;
}

if (flag) {
   return false;
}
```

**3 шаг:** учитывая `NullPointerException` при `!name.equals(human.name);` код будет равным такому:

```
if(name == null) {
   throw new NullPointerException();
} 
if (human.name != null) {
   return false;
}
```